# LibreOffice Calc shows formulas in the cell instead of results

Tags: formula, libreoffice

The LibreOffice Calc (version 6.3.4.2) shows the definition of the formula in the cell instead of executing the formula and displaying the result. What affects the behaviour?

I am starting to use LibreOffice (simple things; newbie).

[image]

**Update**: The original file came from Excel (.xlsx extension). The first row formula was typed manually. The formulas below were filled by dragging the bottom-right handle of the cell. I guess that it should behave similarly to Excel; tha is, the relative cell reference (here A3) should be updated when dragging the formulas to the cells below. Also from that I guess that the formula is treated as a plain text, not as a formula. How to fix that?

**Update 2021-03-23**: I do not know if it was in the old version; however 7.0 implements the hot-key Ctrl+` (Ctrl + backward accent (grave accent)) to switch the modes *show formulas* / *show results*. Try it. :)

Comment: Hi pepr Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/69355/598224

Comment: Thanks @pnorton. The checkbox was off, but switching it on, restart, and switching it on again made it working. I had also to retype the formula. The restart of the Calc may not be necessary. Please, type a short answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to turn on/ off **Show Formulas** in **Libre Office**

**1.** Select **Tools** -> **Options** from the **tools menu** (See **Fig 1**)

**2.** Expand the **Libre office Calc tab** (See **Fig 2**) and **select** **View**. On the **right hand side** **select**/deselect the **formulas** Check box.

[image: Libre Office Tools Options Menu]

**Libre office Calc tab** with **view selected** and on the **right hand side** the **formulas Check box**

[image: Libre Office view Formulas]

Comment: Thanks for the didactic answer. :)

Comment: Hi pepr. Thanks for the dictionary add+ ( didactic ) I do have a soft spot for Libre Office. If you need any further help just let me know. All the best

Comment: This checkbox seems to have no effect for my spreadsheet. Tried all combinations of checking/unchecking and restarting.

Comment: Hi, Nick What version of Libre are you running? What OS are you using? what are you seeing in your sheet? Who has the privileges? As a side note love the mention of "Shadetree Mechanic"  Do you see that much difference with code? Apart from "getting your hands dirty" which could be a metaphor :D

Comment: this is not working for me on "Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10"  using: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS    does anyone have a hint to correct for this ?

Comment: Hi @Melissa. I'm sorry to hear you're having trouble with LibreOffice. What version of LibreOffice Calc are you running? Help->About LibreOffice

Comment: Hi @pnorton I did mention the version in comment above "Version: 6.0.7.3 Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10" is there more around version that would help?

Comment: Hi, @Melissa Thank you for your reply. It appears I am human. I apologise for my mistake; you did indeed include the version. I'm sorry to say I could only recommend updating to the latest  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa). I might also be tempted to update LibreOffice to LibreOffice 7.0.1 (Current version) I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help Melissa. All the best

Comment: @Melissa, if it still shows the formula despite this setting, check if the cell is formatted as "text" – that was the problem for me.  (I've added an answer explaining how to fix that.)

Comment: Is this a bug in Calc?  This seems to be very strange behavior.

Answer (score 15):

Try [pnorton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730886/10366669) first, but if that still doesn't fix it for you, then it might be because the cell where you entered the formula is formatted as "Text".  To fix this, select the cell, then:

- **Format** menu > **Cells...** > **Numbers** tab > **Category**: select *Number* (or any format other than *Text*).

**IMPORTANT: You need to then re-enter the formula.**  The cell's content is technically still *just text*, so you need to force LibreOffice to re-interpret it as a *formula*.  It's not enough to "recalculate" – it's not even enough to click in the formula bar and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.  For example, you could do one of the following:

- Copy the cell, then **Edit** > **Paste Special** > **Paste Unformatted Text**.

Or...

- Click to edit the cell's formula, add a space at the end, delete the space, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

### Before:

[image: formatted as text]

### After:

[image: formatted as number]

(Works for me in LibreOffice version 6.3.6.2 for macOS.)

Comment: But what if **I actually need the type of those cells containing the formula to be the text**? Because my formula is concatenating a couple of other text cells together, so it's producing text again. It's quite common to have formulas producing text, isn't it? There must be some way to have formulas in text cells, I guess.

Comment: Good question – it is indeed common to produce text from formulas.  In that case, I just leave the cell formatted as the default "General" format (which is under the "Number" category, oddly): for me it seems to correctly format the resulting text anyway.  (For my part, the only time I ever deliberately use the "Text" format is when I enter a cell value that _looks_ like a number but I need LibreOffice to interpret it as literal text instead.)

Answer (score 5):

If the spreadsheet file format is correct and the formulas are live and not just text (live formulas lead with the `=` symbol), then the shortcut

```
Ctrl + `
```

will toggle the entire sheet between the values and the formula that generate them. It has the same effect as (in LibreOffice Calc) `Tools > Options... > LibreOffice Calc > View > Formulas` being ticked, but is clearly significantly faster for toggling to review/debug a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a newly created spreadsheet. I solved it by copying the data into another new file and re-entering the formulas. In this second spreadsheet, everything was normal. Strange enough... LibreOffice 6.3.5.2 (x64).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I seem to achieved it by copying the formula into a previously unused cell, deleting all where I want it to be, then copying back

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday.  Neither of the previously mentioned solutions worked for me (changed cell formats, and verified that the display formula option was not accidentally enabled).  It seems like this was an issue with the spelling checker (***right-clicking and selecting `Ignore All` was what ultimately solved my problem!***).

I'm not sure why the spellchecker was insisting to suggest a correction for a `VLOOKUP` formula, but if I find a way to reproduce this weird bug, I'll try reporting it upstream.

Comment: Your case can be similar to my. The weird behavior (in my case) was related to using Ctrl+; (semicolon) when entering the current date. The problem was that when the keyboard was switched to my native language the physically same combination of keys was actually Ctrl+`. So, I was unknowingly switching the mode for displaying/executing the formulas. That could be related also to your switching the language.

Comment: Oooh, I hadn't thought about that! You're right a possibly accidental typo on my part due to keyboard layout. For my work computer I have to use a layout with dead keys, and I would've needed to type ```AltGr + Shift + '``` to get double quotes... which cannot rule out the error between chair and keyboard. I'll have to test it next week!

Answer (score 0):

Text import wizard is not evaluating the formulae. You can enable under other options.[enter image description here][1]

Once this option is checked , restart libreoffice calc. Calc should not show formula. This worked for me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1eyt.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when entering a formula, I get the result; sometimes I just get the formula.  Both can happen on the one sheet.

I found that by selecting a cell which displays only the formula, then left-clicking on the '=' immediately to the left of the box displaying the contents of the currently selected cell, the result of the formula is displayed.

Before any questions about my knowledge, yes, I had started the formula with the '='.